# The structure of "so ...that..." and the meaning of "be to do"

Tags: grammar

> But man's capacities have never been measured; nor are we to judge of what he can do by any precedents, so little has been tried. [Source](http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/hdthoreau/bl-hdtho-wald-1.htm)

Does this "be to do" mean "should"?

And is the structure of this "so... that...?" like in "This is so much fun we can't resist it?" Except in this case, because of the "nor" structure, the "so" part comes afterward?

Comment: The word "so" here refers to "so little", which means "very little". I guess that it refers to the measure of or the judgement on man's capacities.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking, but: “nor are we to judge…” means “we are not to judge…”, which means “we should not judge…” Other alternatives: “it is not for us to judge…” and “it is not our place to judge…”

Comment: 1) Yes, it means "should".  2) Yes, *so* here is like the correlative *so . . . that*.  Here's a similar example of this construction from Quirk et al., p.1142: "He had no need to make speeches, **so** impregnable was his position." == "His position was **so** impregnable **that** he had no need to make speeches."  The phrase containing *so* is fronted, and the correlative *that* is missing from the other half.  In informal style, the *so* phrase is not be fronted: "I couldn't keep my eyes open, I was **so** tired."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted text is equivalent to:

"...and, so little has been tried, we should not judge what he can do."